# OpenGL - Weird "visual" bug

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Why is this happening?
[image]

If I try to draw points it looks like this

[image]

I am using LWJGL and this is the code

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(int i = 0; i < boxes.size() ; i++){

        pBox b = boxes.get(i);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(0.5f,0.3f,0);

        glVertex2f(b.x,b.y);

        glVertex2f(b.x + b.w,b.y);

        glVertex2f(b.x,b.y + b.h);

        glVertex2f(b.x + b.w,b.y + b.h);

        glEnd();
    }

b.x = x coord
b.y = y coord
b.w = width
b.h = height

pBox = custom class :D
```

I can not find why this is happening! I have done it other times (in other programs) and it worked like a charm . This is not an actual square!!!

Library is LWJGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrong order of glVertex2f calls

```
glVertex2f(b.x,b.y);

glVertex2f(b.x + b.w,b.y);

glVertex2f(b.x + b.w,b.y + b.h);

glVertex2f(b.x,b.y + b.h);
```

Comment: Okay thanks. It needs to be like geometry's rules  , clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: @user3310358: Either winding works, it just has to be consistent. OpenGL uses the winding to determine what's the front face, controlled by the front face winding setting.